# "...roof assemblies of buildings to prevent interstitial condensation and of packaging."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "and of packaging" refer to here:

> A vapor barrier (or vapour barrier) is any material used for damp proofing, typically a plastic or foil sheet, that resists diffusion of moisture through the wall, floor, ceiling, or roof assemblies of buildings to prevent interstitial condensation **and of packaging**.

--[Wikipedia page, "Vapor barrier"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_barrier)

Does it refer to "roof of assemblies"? It's a very long sentence, and I got confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not your fault. That last part of the sentence is meaningless where it is. The sentence should read:

> A vapor barrier is any material used for damp proofing, typically a plastic or foil sheet, that resists diffusion of moisture through the wall, floor, ceiling, or roof assemblies of buildings **and of packaging** to prevent interstitial condensation.

This means the barrier resists diffusion of moisture into buildings **and packaging** to prevent interstitial condensation.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is very badly written. Wikipedia is 'crowd sourced', that is, written by ordinary people who are not always fluent writers, as is clearly the case here.

I would rewrite it thus:

> A vapor barrier (or vapour barrier) is any material used for damp
> proofing. It is typically a plastic or foil sheet. The purpose is to resist
> diffusion of moisture through the walls, floors, ceilings, or roof
> assemblies of buildings to prevent interstitial condensation, and also
> to resist diffusion of moisture through packaging.

Further down that page, we see:

> Packaging
>
> The ability of a package to control the permeation and penetration of
> gasses [*sic*] is vital for many types of products. Tests are often
> conducted on the packaging materials but also on the completed
> packages, sometimes after being subjected to flexing, handling,
> vibration, or temperature.